# why the js code can't control the css code?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
        var divBgTop=0;
        function initDivTop()
        {
                divBgTop=document.getElementById("divBg").style.pixelTop;
                alert(divBgTop);
        }
</script>
<style>
.divBgCss
{
        position:absolute;
          left:100px;
    top:100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
        background-color:red;
}
</style>
<body onload="initDivTop()">
<div class="divBgCss" id="divBg"></div>
</body>
```

the result is always 0. why?

Comment: Could the js be loading before the css?  Try linking that to a button, and clicking the button a few seconds after page load.

Comment: your script and style tags should really go in a `<head>` element, not sure if that's causing any problems...also, when I run this code (in a head element), I get undefined, not 0...

Comment: `pixelTop` is an IE-only property.

Comment: but why the result is 0, not 100?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're after is the `offsetTop`:

```
divBgTop=document.getElementById("divBg").offsetTop;
```

Without specifying the unit, you will not get 0 but rather something else but not 100 - you better add unit like `px` so you won't get wrong results when using the code.

Live test case: http://jsfiddle.net/A9Mr2/1/

Answer (score 4):

There <strike>is</strike> was an error in the CSS. You specify 100, but without a unit. Make it 100px (or another unit, if you wish).

Now the only problem is the used propery. pixelTop apparently won't work, but offsetTop will. This is a property of the element, rather than the style, so you'll need:
`getElementById('divBg').offsetTop`

[edit: adjustment and addition after question is modified]

Comment: why the result is 0,not 100. when under IE.

Comment: You do need the units (as you can see, the div is now actually positioned). But you will need the offsetTop property (which is a property of the element, rather than the style). Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/mdCYq/

Answer (score 1):

the pixelTop property is read-only, all others are read/write.
you can set the pixelTop property..like http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/WJrn6/

update:sorry: write-only

Answer (score 0):

I think the code should be:

```
divBgTop = document.getElementById("divBg").style.top;
```

However, this will only read inline styles. To read computed styles you need to... well... [read computed styles](http://blog.stchur.com/2006/06/21/css-computed-style/) :)

Comment: That's not the problem and your suggestion is wrong. Top is not the property. You should use pixelTop (if you want the value in whole pixels) or posTop if you want the actual value in the unit in which it is set. The problem in this case lies in the CSS. See my answer.